# How can I count unread message in firebase chat messages in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I developed a chat using firebase.

Not want to count all message that has unread status and display it to my list of users.

Here is my database.

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have **status:"unread"**

Here is what I did in javascript.

```
<script>
    var ref = new Firebase("https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Users/<?php echo $ae; ?>/");

    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var names="";
        var un=0;
        for (x in snapshot.val()) {
            var xRef = new Firebase("https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Users/<?php echo $ae; ?>/"+x+"/");
            var messagesRef = new Firebase("https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Chats/"+x+" <?php echo $ae; ?>");
            xRef.once("value", function(xsnapshot) {
                var data = xsnapshot.val();
                var name = data["cuname"];
                //console.log(name);

                messagesRef.on("value", function(ysnapshot) {
                    for (y in ysnapshot.val()) {
                        var yRef = new Firebase("https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Chats/"+x+" <?php echo $ae; ?>/"+y+"/");
                        yRef.once("value", function(zsnapshot) {
                            var ydata = zsnapshot.val();
                            var status = ydata["status"];
                            alert(status);
                            if(status=="unread"){
                                un++;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                names += "<li style='padding:10px;border-bottom:1px solid#f2f2f2;'><a href='adminchat.php?id="+x+"&ae=<?php echo $ae; ?>&aeid=<?php echo $aeid; ?>&custo="+name+"'>"+name+" "+un+"</a></li>";
            });
        }
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=names;
    });


    </script>
```

I can't get the total of unread message.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), a very common thing in Firebase:

```
...
//console.log(name);

// NEW
messagesRef.orderByChild("status").equalTo("unread").on("value", function(ysnapshot) {
    var unread = ysnapshot.numChildren();
});

names += "<li style='padding:10px;border-bottom:1px solid#f2f2f2;'><a href='adminchat.php?id="+x+"&ae=<?php echo $ae; ?>&aeid=<?php echo $aeid; ?>&custo="+name+"'>"+name+" "+un+"</a></li>";
...
```

- Assuming `"https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Chats/"+x+" <?php echo $ae; ?>/"` resolves to something like: `"https://mosbeau-cd349.firebaseio.com/Chats/10736 ONLINESHOP/"`

So all you're doing is getting this node, `10736 ONLINESHOP`, and retrieving by its children having a child `status` with value `unread`.

Comment: hi, i tried to add this code but im getting an error messagesRef.orderByChild is not a function

Comment: hi please help me with my problem. im still not getting the solution. sorry im new to firebase and javascript. i really need help about this problem. thanks.